# jQuery focus event seems not working in qUnit test

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I have just started with qUnit testing framework, but I have stuck on very strange behavior. I would like to simulate DOM element focus event, because its used in application which I am going to test. But it seems that focus event is not propagated to the subscribed objects. For example I have this simple code snippet:

```
$("#myinput").on("focus",function()
{
    $("#myinput").val("focus triggered");
});
$("#myinput").trigger("focus");
```

This works fine in simple javascript file, jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/233kg/16/). But when I try to run similar code in qUnit test function, focus event handler is never called. My qUnit test looks like this:

```
test("trigger test", function ()
{
    expect(1);
    $("#customerInput").on("focus", function()
    {
        ok(true, "focus trigerred");
    });
    $("#customerInput").focus();
});
```

But ok function is never called and test always fails, since it expects one assert. Is there any solution how to simulate the fire focus event in qUnit tests?

**EDIT**

I have tried to trigger and catch custom event, lets say `$("#customerInput").trigger("myevent")` and `$("#customerInput").on("myevent", function() {...})` and noow it works. It means that the problem is somehow related directly to the focus event.

Comment: Some limitation may be ..

Comment: Are you sure your test is running when dom is ready. http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/CHEha/1/ works for me. Check `    console.log($("#customerInput").length);` if this is not 0.

Comment: I call all test functions in jQuery DOM ready function. Its pretty weird. I have also find out another strange behavior, see my update.

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented this using JQuery's `trigger()` function:

```
var focusEvent = $.Event("focus"),
   $input = $('#id-of-input-to-focus-on');

$input.trigger(focusEvent);
```

This allows testing of JavaScript functions that are triggered when focusing on an text input field, for example.

The QUnit documentation for testing user interactions is [here](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#testing-user-actions).